# Search engine url, removal get data from empty forms fields. Django, queryset

Tags: django, forms, django-queryset

I create a simple search engine in django. I would like to get a nice URL from here, even if a field will not be selected.

For example, I have a simple form in my **forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    province = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PROVINCE, required=False)
    brand = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BRAND, required=False)
    price = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

In my **views.py**, I use it in such a way:

```
def search(request)
    #data - returns data GET or False
    province = request.GET.get('province', False)
    brand = request.GET.get('brand', False)
    price = request.GET.get('price', False)
    #search engine
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    query = Car.objects.all()
    if province:
        query = query.filter(province=province)
    if brand:
        query = query.filter(brand=brand)
    if price:
        query = query.filter(price__gtl=price)

    return render(request, 'searh.html', {'query' :query})
```

After filling out the form in the template, URL it looks something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?brand=Ford&model=&price=
```

Can I show only the fields that have been selected (As below), if so how to do it?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?brand=Ford

*does not show '&model=&price='because the user has not entered anything
```

Comment: If you have many fields it is better to use POST method instead of GET so the fields won't appear at all in your URL but will be passed to the server. You use in your html form `method="post"` and instead of `request.GET.get()` use `request.POST.get()`. Another solution if you insist on using `GET` is to parse your querystring in javascript before loading it. Get every variable value and create your string manually if it has a value.

Comment: Just as an aside you should take a look at [`django_filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html)

Comment: ultimately my form will consist of many fields along with filtering by foreign keys. I think that in this case django-filters may not be suitable.